# sending ctrl-c in bash to perf command

Tags: bash, process, perf, sigint

The perf-stat command in linux runs until crtl-c is pressed. I am trying to use this command in script to profile a loop. The recommended solution to simulate sending crtl-c is to issue a kill command with -2 or -SIGINT flag.
However this does not work for me. I am on RHEL.

The script more or less looks as follows:

```sh
for i in {1..12}
do
pid=$1
perf stat -e dTLB-loads -p $pid > perf.out&
perf_pid=$!
sleep 10
kill -SIGINT $perf_pid
done
```

Even after the kill the perf process is still active. All the ctrl-c's are executed at the end when the script gets over.

Comment: Isn't `$!` the `pid` of the `sleep`? Maybe try setting `p=$!` before `sleep`, then use `$p` with `kill`?

Comment: @mkayaalp that was typo.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the  [man page for perf](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/perf-stat.1.html), I came across the --control option  which seems is the  proper approach to profile a portion of running command.
However, this option is not available on RHEL .

I was able find workaround by using the -INT option for kill [mentioned here](https://serverfault.com/questions/967054/how-to-gracefully-kill-linux-perf-tool-process). For some reason -2 or -SIGINT doesn't work on RHEL.